# How do you calculate Array Modifier with Relative Offset?

Tags: modifiers

[image]

The pillar at center's width is 0.2

So I added 0.2 to basic 1.0 value of Array Modifier offeset

but it didn't work as I expected.

How do you calculate this to close the gap?

Comment: Just use constant offset instead.

Comment: @Crantisz Thank you for the reply but that didn't work. when I apply constant value x with 1.45 or relative value x with 1.160, there's no gap between middle pillar and the second array of the object which I don't get. Because pillar's width is 0.2, so array x value, I think, has to be 1.2 but the result confuses me. so...

Comment: Check scale, maybe you need to apply scale

Comment: @Crantisz sorry to keep bothering but what do you mean by Check scale? It its 1. and the first one of array fits exactly where it is supposed(between the pillars). problem starts from the second one

Comment: can you share the file? I just can't understand how you use the array

Comment: @Crantisz I'm sorry it must be my English that confuses you. heres file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RQasgWjQbMaAPn6PypxeGjUlfA8nGQez/view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, i said, use constant offset instead relative, it's much easier:

[image]

"Relative" doesn't mean "length of object plus something", this means "length of object multiply by given number". Relative offset is a factor, that multiply with length of the object. In your case is 1.25 for top block and 1 for others.

If want to calculate it, lets try:

Offset in m is 1.45 (1.25+0.2) relative unit is 1.25. So to get offset you need to divide 1.45 by 1.25

```
1.45/1.25=1.16
```

So, 1.16 is offset in relative units.

For bottom blocks with 1m length  relative units will be different (block has 1m length), so offset will be `1.45 / 1 = 1.45`

Answer (score 0):

Relative offset is calculated in relation to the **width of the first element**. And 1.0 means **adjacent**  elements,**without** gaps (see the image below)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply but that didn't work. when I apply constant value x with 1.45 or relative value x with 1.160, there's no gap between middle pillar and the second array of the object which I don't get. Because pillar's width is 0.2, so array x value, I think, has to be 1.2 but the result confuses me. so...